# Jquery very sensitive "onchange" method

Tags: jquery, onchange

is there a way to optimize the "onchange" method for an text input field? Let's say if I use the microphone to enter a value into the input field, I never use the mouse to change the content inside the text field, then it doesn't give me any response, unless I put my pointer in the textfield and then out again.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class=".target" />
```

Jquery:

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/input) event is probably what you're looking for -- it's like `change`, except it fires every time the text is changed, without waiting until it loses focus.

```
$( ".target" ).on("input", function() {
    alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N3zVA/1/)

Comment: Thanks, it worked great! I'm working with "x-webkit-speech" for the input field, and just realized that there may be a callback-function for that, but this code works great! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

At the end I actually found this to be very useful in this case, the "webkitspeechchange":

```
$('#speech').bind('webkitspeechchange', function() {
    alert($(this).val())
});
```